# Sonata admin with model layer

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Is there a way to use a custom model instead of an entity with sonata admin ?

When trying to do so, I get:

```
No entity manager defined for class AppBundle\Model\OrderModel
```

Or in other words, how can I use fat models with sonata admin ? ( DDD )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you would like to override the sonata order entity class and you can do that when you type in parameters.yml following:

```
#for order entity
sonata.order.order.class: YOURNAMESPACE/ENTITY
#for order element entity
sonata.order.order_element.class: YOURNAMESPACE/ENTITY
#for order manager
sonata.order.order.manager.class: YOURNAMESPACE/ENTITY
#for order element manager
sonata.order.order_element.manager.class: YOURNAMESPACE/ENTITY
```

Comment: No, sorry, I understand the confusion. I am NOT using the sonata ecommerce bundle, only the sonata admin. In my example I used an order model, but it could have been any model.

Comment: Do you enable your bundle or model folder in: doctrine -> orm -> entity_manager -> mappings: configuration?

Comment: That is not the problem nor the question. I want to use a supplementary model layer, as an entity is not really a model but only a data container. So my model class "uses" the doctrine entity as data layer. But as far as I can see, sonata admin only works with entities !?

Comment: I am not sure, but if I userstand right you can try to create service with name sonata.admin.manager.YOUR_MODEL who extend Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager. After that in the sonata admin configuration chnage manager_type of your service 
    <tag   ...... manager_type="YOUR_MODEL" ....../>